# Pandas Dataframe, how to group columns together in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas Dataframe and i want to group some of the columns to build higher levels columns:

Exemple : i have

```
Index       A       B       C       D
    1    0.25     0.3    0.25    0.66
    2    0.25     0.3    0.25    0.66
    3    0.25     0.3    0.25    0.66
```

and i want

```
    Index              AB        ||           CD
    Subindex       A   |      B  ||      C    |      D 
    1            0.25  |    0.3  ||   0.25    |    0.66
    2            0.25  |    0.3  ||   0.25    |    0.66
    3            0.25  |    0.3  ||   0.25    |    0.66
```

Thank you for your help...

Comment: ***"i have "***,***"i want "***...and you've tried?

Comment: Check multiple index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `groupby` / `concat` hack

```
m = {'A': 'AB', 'B': 'AB', 'C': 'CD', 'D': 'CD'}
pd.concat(dict((*df.groupby(m, 1),)), axis=1)

         AB         CD      
          A    B     C     D
Index                       
1      0.25  0.3  0.25  0.66
2      0.25  0.3  0.25  0.66
3      0.25  0.3  0.25  0.66
```

Note that with this method it is possible to select an arbitrary subset of the columns in the original DataFrame, whereas the alternative answer appears to require a valid dictionary mapping for **all** values in the parent DataFrame

Comment: so sorry for that but how can you group AB and CD now in a higher level ?

At the end i would like to have DataFrame ['ABCD'] ['AB] ['A'] for example.
The same logic doesn't seem to work...

Comment: What if I a have a column "F" that I don't want to group?

Comment: `pd.concat(dict((*df.drop(cols2skip, axis=1).groupby(m, 1),)), axis=1)` where `cols2skip` is a list of columns to not include.  If there is only one column `pd.concat(dict((*df.drop('F', axis=1).groupby(m, 1),)), axis=1)`

Answer (score 4):

Create a dictionary to define your mapping and use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html). If needed you can also specify  `names=['level_0', 'level_1']` to add names.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': 'AB', 'B': 'AB', 'C': 'CD', 'D': 'CD'}
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([*zip(map(d.get, df), df)])
# Equivalently
# df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(d[col], col) for col in df.columns])
```

Output:

```
         AB         CD      
          A    B     C     D
Index                       
1      0.25  0.3  0.25  0.66
2      0.25  0.3  0.25  0.66
3      0.25  0.3  0.25  0.66
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but i've already done a double for loop to fill a new dataframe like you said, and it seems that it's not the fastest option. Is there no possible way to make the changes in place ?

Comment: @Tbertin your question/comment doesn't make a lot of sense.  This answer does alter the dataframe in place and should be pretty fast as it is only altering the columns object.

Comment: @ALollz `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([*zip(map(d.get, df), df)])` as a fun alternative.  Your's is more readable of course (-:

Comment: Thanks :D. Definitely need to just commit that syntax to memory very soon.