# Group columns from column to column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

[image]

and I want to group the answers like the following

[image]

I tried to use multindex, but  it won’t work.

Comment: 1- please provide the input/output data as **text**, 2- what have you tried and how did it not work? 3- what is the grouping logic?

Comment: There should not be any grouping logic. I just want to give the grouping by the header manually. For example, "Answer 1" -  "Answer 2" = "Group 1"

Comment: Do you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53714192/pandas-dataframe-how-to-group-columns-together-in-python) ? Columns names are unique?

Comment: Thank you, i will try it. It will take a moment because there is a lot of grouping action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.MultiIndex.from_array` to manually craft your custom index:

```
new_level = ['GROUP1', 'GROUP1', 'GROUP1', 'GROUP2', 'GROUP2', 'GROUP3', 'GROUP3']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([new_level, df.columns])
```

example input:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
0  X  X  X  X  X
```

output:

```
>>> df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[1,1,2,2,3], df.columns])
>>> df
   1     2     3
   A  B  C  D  E
0  X  X  X  X  X
```